# Selenium в связке с PHP не может запустить браузер

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

Установил WebDriver, вроде всё работает. Запускаю таким образом:

```
DISPLAY=:99 xvfb-run -a -n 1 -l -s "-screen 0, 1024x768x8" java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar
```

Запускается. После чего с помощью PHP пытаюсь подключиться и открыть браузер:

```
namespace Facebook\WebDriver;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, DesiredCapabilities::chrome());
```

При запуске возникает ошибка:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /root/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php on line 127 and defined in /root/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/DesiredCapabilities.php on line 33
```

Сам процесс Selenium выдаёт:

```
2017-08-17 11:41:56.927:INFO:osjshC.ROOT:qtp405662939-9: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet-675d3402: Initialising WebDriverServlet
11:41:57.192 INFO - Binding default provider to: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService
11:41:57.193 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.BeginSession@51253f85
11:41:57.200 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
11:41:57.262 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName=chrome, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, }
11:41:57.267 INFO - Capabilities {browserName=chrome, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, } matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
11:41:57.268 INFO - Capabilities {browserName=chrome, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, } matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
2017-08-17 11:41:57.305:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp405662939-9: /wd/hub/session
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.isPrimitiveOrString(JsonPrimitive.java:278)
        at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.setValue(JsonPrimitive.java:101)
        at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.<init>(JsonPrimitive.java:65)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ExceptionHandler.lambda$execute$0(ExceptionHandler.java:82)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:88)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.handle(WebDriverServlet.java:247)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.doPost(WebDriverServlet.java:151)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.service(WebDriverServlet.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

И здесь, уже не знаю в какую сторону смотреть, гугл не помог.

Comment: а у вас точно установлен firefox? При запуске указываете capability firefox, а в логе селениума - chrome:
`11:41:57.262 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName=chrome, platformName=ANY, platform=ANY, }`

Comment: Я извиняюсь. Просто при тестировании пробовал и firefox и chrome, а логи, получается, перепутал. Но это не страшно в данном случае, при попытке использовать как firefox, так и chrome - ошибка одинаковая. Я понимаю, исходя из ошибки, что данные передаются некорректные (массив должен быть, а передаётся null?), но так как делаю по инструкции, одной из интернета, не могу понять что именно не так делаю.

Comment: Но на всякий случай поправил код php в вопросе, поменял строчку с указанием фокса на строчку с хромом.

Comment: Ещё заметил такой момент: при переходе в своём браузере по адресу http://(hub ip):5555/wd/hub - открывается окно со списком сессий и возможностью создать новую. При создании запрос на страницу session выдаёт ошибку 500. Может сам WebDriver установлен с ошибкой или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: 3.5 свежая версия. Попробуйте или добавить опцию `-enablePassThrough false` в запуск сервера. Или старую версию.

Comment: так, подождите: вы работаете через Grid или standalone? В вашем примере, вы запускаете в режиме standalone, но в комментарии пишете про grid `http://(hub ip):5555/wd/hub`

Comment: Я делаю, как показано в данном примере: https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver , там сказано что нужен standalone , а хост подключения указывается как $host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; - просто вместо локалхоста я решил перейти на сам ip адрес и посмотреть что будет - там ошибка, т.е. не через PHP даже, а напрямую - не получается создать сессию для браузера.

Comment: а порт `4444` открыт? Вы же теперь стучитесь через внешний интерфейс.

Comment: Я в итоге запустил браузер (судя по логам), но всё равно сыпались ошибки. В данный момент разбираться в них не представляется возможным и я решил свою задачу иначе. Спасибо большое за помощь:)